# how to do ordered sorting with by = argument in tbl_summary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am creating a table 1 from a dataset which consist of two groups "Case" and "Control" using the tbl_summary function.

As it naturally sorts into two columns with "Case" on the left and "Control" on the right, I get this table:

[table obtained from tbl_summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYtO0.png)

However, I would like to have the "Control" group appearing on the left.
I have tried to re-order the factors, placing "Control" first before "Case". However, "Case" still appears on the left - I'm assuming this is because it's following alphanumeric order.

How could I get around this? It's a simple adjustment but I am clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to reverse the ordering of the the variable in `tbl_summary(by=)` is using the `forcats::fct_rev()` function before you pipe a data frame to `tbl_summary()`.

Example below. Happy Programming!

```r
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  select(trt, age, marker) %>%
  mutate(trt = forcats::fct_rev(trt)) %>%   # reverse the ordering of trt variable
  tbl_summary(by = trt)
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed that using forcats::fct_relevel() didn't work (and this solution didn't work, either), until I updated the gtsummary package... which is wild cause I know I first installed it well after August 2020.