# How can I get `gtsummary::add_difference()` to use the expected sign for the difference result without changing order of columns?

Tags: difference, gtsummary

- Aim: To compare the effect of 'Drug B' to 'Drug A' on marker level by using the `add_difference()` function **and** keep 'Drug A' column before 'Drug B'

**1. initial table**

```r
library(gtsummary) # version ‘1.7.0’
packageVersion("gtsummary") 
#> [1] '1.7.0'

table_1 <- 
  trial |>
  select(trt, marker) |>
  tbl_summary(by = trt) |>
  add_difference()

table_1 |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable so it will display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **Drug B**, N = 102 | **Difference** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marker Level (ng/mL) | 0.84 (0.24, 1.57) | 0.52 (0.19, 1.20) | 0.20 | -0.05, 0.44 | 0.12 |
| Unknown | 6 | 4 |  |  |  |

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

- Expected order of columns : 'Drug A' then 'Drug B'
- Expected Difference: 'Drug B' - 'Drug A' = 0.52 - 0.84 = -0.20
- Problem in table_1 : columns are in the expected order but sign is not the expected one - it seems it calculate 'first column' minus 'second column'

**2. attempt with `stats::relevel()` : same as table_1**

```r
library(gtsummary) # version ‘1.7.0’
library(stats)
packageVersion("gtsummary") 
#> [1] '1.7.0'

table_2 <- 
  trial |>
  select(trt, marker) |>
  mutate(trt = stats::relevel(as.factor(trt), ref = 'Drug A')) |>
  tbl_summary(by = trt) |>
  add_difference()

table_2 |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable so it will display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **Drug B**, N = 102 | **Difference** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marker Level (ng/mL) | 0.84 (0.24, 1.57) | 0.52 (0.19, 1.20) | 0.20 | -0.05, 0.44 | 0.12 |
| Unknown | 6 | 4 |  |  |  |

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

- Problem in table_2: sign is still not the expected one

**3. attempt with forcats::fct_rev**

```r
## inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/63436888/6176250
library(gtsummary) # version ‘1.7.0’
library(forcats)
packageVersion("gtsummary") 
#> [1] '1.7.0'

table_3 <- 
  trial |>
  select(trt, marker) |>
  # reverse order of the by variable
  mutate(trt = forcats::fct_rev(trt)) |>
  tbl_summary(by = trt) |>
  add_difference() 

table_3|> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable so it will display on stackoverflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug B**, N = 102 | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **Difference** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marker Level (ng/mL) | 0.52 (0.19, 1.20) | 0.84 (0.24, 1.57) | -0.20 | -0.44, 0.05 | 0.12 |
| Unknown | 4 | 6 |  |  |  |

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

- Expected difference now as expected but columns order are not

**4. explorations**
I searched on gtsummary [vignettes](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/index.html), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtsummary) and [github](https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues) pages without finding a solution.

I also tried to export `as_gt()` but could not find a way to reorder the colums: hard to find the right column names to use with `gt::cols_move()`.

**5. questions**

- question 1: is it possible to reorder columns for table_3?
- question 2: is there a way to tell `gtsummary::add_difference()` to calculate 'second column' minus 'first column'?

Thank you for this very useful package!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example below on how to change the order of columns

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.0'

# run `show_header_names()` to print the underlying column names
tbl <-
  trial |> 
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    include = age, 
    missing = "no"
  ) |> 
  add_difference() |> 
  # switch the order of the columns
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x |> dplyr::relocate(stat_2, .before = stat_1)
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for the rapid response to my first question that allow me to continue working. For question 2, I guess it might require development. Still, I am intrigued as to why the difference is the usual way we use it, certainly in the field of epidemiology.

Comment: I've published 100s of manuscripts, been on the editorial board for top journals, and the default difference is exactly how differences are meant to be reported. While the package provides functions modify the tables for various other needs, I don't think we'll implement options to reverse the calculation.